# Suggestion about automatic map creation problem

Tags: gis, arcgis, qgis, geopandas, arcpy

I have two layers, first one is the ROAD layer and second one is the PARCEL layer as shown in Figure 1. I can get the data both in dxf and shp formats.

[image]

My task is to compute the area of intersection between ROAD and PARCEL layer, this is the easy part. I can compute intersection using QGIS or Geopandas easily. However, the difficult part is creating maps for each of the parcel. Sometimes, I have to create more then a hundred maps for each project.  For mapping, there is a template that I have to use, which is similiar to Figure 2. Also, some attribute data should be included in the map, such as owner of the parcel. 
[image]

These maps should be in both pdf and dxf format. Each map should be in A3 size. To be able to produce such maps, what libraries or programming languages should I use? I have experience in geopandas library but I am not sure if it is enough for this task. 
Shoud I try QGIS plugin development or ArcPY? Could you please share your experiences and ideas about this problem?

I am looking forward to hearing from you,

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a *specific* programming question? If not, I think this would be better received at gis.statckexchange.com

Comment: to get you headed in the right direction, you don't even need arcpy for this. "Data Driven Pages" in Esri's software handles this use case easily

Comment: Dear Paul H thank you for your comments. I tried Data Driven Pages of the ArcGIS and Atlas of QGIS but did not solve my problem.  Because of this reason, I  think the only way to solve this problem is developing my own program. In such a situation, which programming language or tools should I use?

Comment: general software recommendations aren't on-topic for stack overflow. i recommend (again) migrating this to the GIS.SE site

Comment: Thank you Paul H